# When I start a new project NetBeans unexpected exception appear?

Tags: java, netbeans

[image]

> unexpected exception could not initialized class sun.awt.shell
>
> jdk:8u121 .. netBeans:8.2 ..  platform:windows 10-64bit

Comment: I suggest you reinstall both Java and NetBeans

Answer (score 1):

I have same error because i installed SE development Kit 8 and 9 .After uninstall 9 it is working fine without this error please check through control panel .hope this is bit help if you have same error.

Answer (score 0):

I hope these might help you

Interesting to see

"NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2"

in your log. It seems this class from JDK is missing at runtime. It is weird and without a good explanation - see also e.g. an old bug and its comments at http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6583864

Also based on the last messages in your log, the JVM may have not crashed. Isn't the java process still alive (without any UI showing)? You can find out by running "jps -m" command in your console.

Did you install JDK and NB before upgrading to Windows 10 or after the upgrade?

It would be worth trying to uninstall JDK, NB, remove also NB's userdir and cachedir, and try fresh install of JDK and NB again.

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir

credit goes to NetBeans Community Antonin Nebuzelsky